# How to test the https connection of a Nexus Repository Management server

Tags: https, nexus

I've just setup a Nexus server. I know that my http connection works since I get the "Welcome" page which gets loaded via http. However, I don't see any components when I browse the repositories (the default repos like "Maven Central" are configured).

I don't really know whether it's normal that there aren't any components shown or if my https connection doesn't work (it's quite a hassle with the company's proxy that's why I'm suspicious). So, how can I test whether the https connection works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. Repositories will only contain artifacts once you have retrieved some of them via the repository manager. E.g. configure Maven as documented in the [tools chapter](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config.html) and they proxied artifacts will show up in proxy repos.

You can try to use the Browse Remote tab on the Central proxy repository to verify that a connection to it does work.

For hosted repos you would publish to them.

If you need to connect to the internet via a proxy server you can configure that as well http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/configxn-sect-customizing-server.html

Check out the documentation for more tips.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I followed these instructions https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/using.html#browse-browse and still can't see any components. Am I right to assume that there isn't a https connection? Is there any extensive log? The common "Log Viewer" doesn't provide any information (I expected something like "Proxy: Host not found" etc.).

Comment: LIke I said in my answer... unless you configure a build or some other tool to request artifacts from the repository manager there will be none. If you are using v3 follow the instructions at http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/maven.html#maven-sect-single-group